# is there a way to convert the time format in the mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

the date style stored in the database is as this : `1310783109`.

eg: the date field is `updatetime`. when i using this:

```
SELECT updatetime from node_software
```

then in my template file i using this `{updatetime}`. it outputs  `1310783109`. is there a way to format the date in the sql command then to make the output like this `07-28`. namely, the month-the day. thank you.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`updatetime`, '%m-%d') AS `updatetime` 
  FROM `node_software`
```

Comment: i am sorry., the output are all to this:01-01.why ?

Comment: @zhu They shouldn't be. Unless all your dates are January 1st, I'm not sure why you'd get that result.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%m-%d") as mydate

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1310783109, "%m-%d") as mydate
```

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME actually takes format string as second argument, so DATE_FORMAT is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

[FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Why are you not using MySQL's native date/time datatypes anyway?